# Encoder Decoder model for parameter extraction from text input

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, encoder

I have an input as text from which I want to extract parameters as given in example below.

Input:

```
"client need to pay penalty of 10%  of amount  if there is delay in project for more than 3 months"
```

and output:

```
penalty = 10% and delay = 3
```

assuming there are N number of such parameters.

Here I have thought of using encoder and decoder model . Where I use RNN as encoder for text input  Now I wonder what would be  decoder architecture that will output N parameters and their values.
what is alternative architecture to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Some popular methods for POS-tagging are *Hidden Markov Model* (HMM) and *Conditional Random Field (CRF)* [book](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/8.pdf).

But you could use any recurrent networks (RNN, LSTM, bi-LSTM), CNNs or Transformers, to process your sequence of embeddings.

One could also use BERT (or other pre-trained models) to perform Name Entity Recognition [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-with-bert-in-pytorch-a454405e0b6a).

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question, does it?

Comment: I want to  check how encoder/decoder architecture will fit in here. when  input/output both sequence, I can use RNN for both encoder/decoder.